# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'TYPE_CONFIGURABLE' in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a piece of code that I am converting from magento 1 to magento 2. This is the code that has been converted

```
$productType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE;
    $bundleType = null; 
    if (null !== $mainVariationIndex) {
        $isActive = isset($item['variations'][$mainVariationIndex]['isActive']) ? $item['variations'][$mainVariationIndex]['isActive'] : false;
        if (count($item['variations']) > 1) {
            $productType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE;
        }
        if (isset($item['variations'][$mainVariationIndex]['bundleType'])) {
            $bundleType = $item['variations'][$mainVariationIndex]['bundleType'];
            $productType = $bundleType === \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE ?
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE : \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE;
        }
    }
```

I am having the issue in this line

```
$productType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE;
```

The above line was like this in magento 1.9

```
$productType = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE;
```

Now when I am using the constant TYPE_CONFIGURABLE in magento 2, I am getting an error Undefined class constant. So I checked for constant in file Type.php in catalog module for magento 2 but did not find it. There were only three constants defined

```
const TYPE_SIMPLE = 'simple';

const TYPE_BUNDLE = 'bundle';

const TYPE_VIRTUAL = 'virtual';
```

So I thought it must be defined in some other file but could not find it.
Now my question is should I use configurable as a string like below

```
$productType = 'configurable';
```

for my code in magento 2 or there is some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Magento2, we have a separate module for configurable products (`vendor/module-configurable-product` as `Magento_ConfigurableProduct`).

So you can find the text `configurable` from this constant & use it: `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE`